gcloud artifacts delete versions/digests not freeing up space in artifact repository
I'm developing a cloud build pipeline that deploys a cloud run job among other tasks and after the whole process is completed I want to clean up the artifact repository so it doesn't take any more space.
However whenever I try to delete an image version using gcloud artifacts versions delete --delete-tags or gcloud artifacts docker images delete --delete-tags the repository reports the same size as before, even when the version/digest was effectively deleted.
The deletion of versions/digests works perfectly fine when I trigger it manually from the console and the size gets reduced as it should.
Does anyone know if I'm maybe missing something here? I filed a bug request just in case this is really a bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/343503172
